# Pattern Lock can't be disabled through settings

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

my girlfriend set up a pattern lock and we're unable to remove the pattern now. The Settings show the disabled Option and the text: "Admin, Guideline or login data prevent this". So I disabled all device admins, deleted all VPNs, removed all Login Data and found out that this helped nothing. 
The device is a HUAWEI P8 Lite (no root/no bootloader enabled) running on Marshmallow.
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have Android Pay or Mobile Iron (for corp access) setup? Maybe those are requiring pattern lock to be enabled.

Answer (score -1):

If you have locked it through third-party app then try this. If there is *Advanced Protection* enabled on your pattern locking app, then you you need to deactivate the Advance Protection. You can do this by going to Settings >Security >Device Administrator >Uncheck the app. After this disable/force stop/uninstall the app. If you have put pattern on settings too then Goto SafeMode. Google it

> Goto SafeMode [Your device brand] [Your device model]

After going into SafeMode do the above steps and after that restart your phone. Hope it will help.